# PHP Curl get contents from external site

Tags: php, html, curl

I tried to get a contents from our main website into microsite, so the microsite only pull the contents from the main site without DB.

I am used curl for this, as I am new on the curl when i tried to parsing the content only showed the tittle, img, and teaser text (which is good so far). But what I want next is, when user clicked the title with link to the details article not jumping to the main site (original site/source).

Any clue how to do this?

my code currently is:

```
$curl = curl_init('http://www.mainsite.com/indeks/64/');

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

$page = curl_exec($curl);

if(curl_errno($curl)) // check for execution errors
{
    echo 'Scraper error: ' . curl_error($curl);
    exit;
}

curl_close($curl);

$regex = '/<ul class="list_indeks">(.*?)<\/ul>/s';
if ( preg_match($regex, $page, $list) )
    echo $list[0];
else 
    print "Not found";
```

Thanks for the helps

Comment: You need to rewrite all relative URLs in the page to be absolute URLs that point to the main site.

Comment: Hi @Barmar, thanks for the responded. As I mentioned below, I am really new for this, can you give the example how to do this?

Comment: It's pretty complicated, I'm not sure how to do it properly.

Comment: Thanks btw, I tried to take a look on google than, for the tuts or something else

Comment: You're not going to find this in any tutorial, it's too unusual and complicated.

Comment: Ok, than :) thanks for response